# How to configure uwsgi.yml for metricbeat properly?

Tags: uwsgi, devops, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I have enabled uwsgi module for metricbeat. But, logs doesn't appear on kibana. I am using default uwsgi.yml for metricbeat and it looks like this.

```
# Module: uwsgi
# Docs:     https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.5/metricbeat-modul-uwsgi.html

- module: uwsgi
  #metricsets:
  #  - status
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["tcp://127.0.0.1:9090"]
```

I've even tried to find port uwsgi is running on, but I failed. How should I change uwsgi.yml file to make it work properly? I've never used uwsgi myself and my linux knowledge is pretty basic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line in your uwsgi config (normally in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/yourapp.ini`):

```
stats = 127.0.0.1:9090
```